# How to set currentUserId value in John Papa - CodeCamper SPA application

Tags: single-page-application, hottowel

I have a question regarding CodeCamper app by John Papa. In the `config.js`
file, the `currentUserId` value is hardcoded to `3`. I want to set this value with
the SQL employee table unique id after it has authenticated using a Login
page.

The login page is already working, I just need to set the `currentUserId` value to make it all work, anyone has an elegant solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add an API action that returns the currentUserId.

In your config.js, just add a loadUser function to get the currentUserId from the API and then update the currenUserId variable accordingly.

This loadUser function should be called after the user has been authenticated. Without more details on how you do the authentication, I won't be able to say where exactly this should happen.